# I can not find away to install Qt wayland

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu, face-recognition, wayland

I am trying to run a face recognition with open cv but i keep getting this error `qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins"`

I have had a google around but i cant find anything that works. iv tried using Pacman to install it but cant. i am trying to run it on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Full code

```
import cv2
import os
import face_recognition
import numpy as np



# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#loop over all the images in the folder and put them in a list
known_face_encodings = []
known_face_names = []
for file in os.listdir("known/"):
    if file.endswith(".jpg"):
        #load the image
        known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("known/" + file)
        #get the face encoding
        known_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
        #add the encoding to the list
        known_face_encodings.append(known_face_encoding)
        #add the name to the list
        known_face_names.append(file[:-4])



# Initialize some variables
face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

#loop over the frames
while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25) 

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Only process every other frame of video to save time
    if process_this_frame:
        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"

            # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


    # Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

   #save the image
    cv2.imwrite("Tested/test.jpg", frame)
```

Im not sure why its doing this. my next guess is that it is installed but in the wrong place. or there is another way of doing what i want to do with this application.